# Sorting on the date column properly

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have the following query that return my data as the example bellow

```
Nov 1 2017
Nov 21 2017
Oct 29 2017
Oct 30 2017
```

I would like my data to be return as is

```
Oct 29 2017
Oct 30 2017
Nov 1 2017
Nov 21 2017
```

I have tried the orderby clause on the date value and I had no luck...

Here is my full query where I would like to incorporate my sort functionality.

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(11),E1_INTEGRATE.DBO.ConvertJulianDateToStd(WLDRQJ)) AS 'Due date', 
    WLDOCO, 
    E1_INTEGRATE.DBO.ConvertJulianDateToStd(PDPDDJ), 
    PDTORG as 'Buyer', 
    PDDOCO, 
    'Supplier' = 
                 (SELECT 
                     ABALPH 
                  FROM ps_prod.proddta.F0101 
                  WHERE PHAN8 = ABAN8
                  ), 
    WLKITL

FROM ps_prod.proddta.F3112 -- Work Order Routing

INNER JOIN
    ps_prod.proddta.F4311 -- Purchase order detail
      ON    
        substring(WLRORN, patindex('%[^0]%',WLRORN), 8) = CAST(PDDOCO as VARCHAR(8)) 
        AND WLRKCO = PDKCOO 

INNER JOIN
    ps_prod.proddta.F4301
     ON
       PDDOCO = PHDOCO

INNER JOIN
    ps_prod.proddta.F57JTDT f1
     ON
      F4311.PDCNID = f1.JDDOCO
      AND f1.JDZZCAT5 = 30
      AND f1.JDZZFN5 = 20
      AND f1.JDZZFLDV = 'Yes'

INNER JOIN
   ps_prod.proddta.F57JTDT f2
    ON
     F4311.PDCNID = f2.JDDOCO
     AND f2.JDZZCAT5 = 30
     AND f2.JDZZFN5 = 70
     AND f2.JDZZFLDV = 'Yes'

WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),E1_INTEGRATE.DBO.ConvertJulianDateToStd(WLDRQJ) ) < 30
    AND RTRIM(WLRORN) > ' '
    AND E1_INTEGRATE.DBO.ConvertJulianDateToStd(WLDRQJ) > CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()),101))
    AND PDAEXP = 0  -- Extended Price
    AND PDUOPN > 0  -- Unit open quantity
    AND PDNXTR = '400'
```

Comment: What is the name and datatype of the field in question?

Comment: I tried this at the end of the query and no luck...  order by convert(date,'Due date') ASC

Comment: The 'Due date' is the name of the field I want to order by....

Comment: Due date is a function result.  What is the name and datatype of the database field?

Answer (score 0):

try this at the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar, DueDate, 112)
```

**UPDATE:**

actually DueDate is not your field you want to order by, it is just the alias at the end of the query, when I look at your query JulianDate seems ok to order by, so you may also try this:

```
ORDER BY WLDRQJ
```

Comment: No luck... ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: is this a suitable option for you: removing DISTINCT keyword and GROUPing by every column in select? so you can order by anything you want...

Comment: @Noxthron, same ORDER BY rules for GROUP BY as for SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: you are welcome, please accept as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
    DISTINCT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(12),E1_INTEGRATE.DBO.ConvertJulianDateToStd(WLDRQJ),107),',','') AS 'Due date'

Comment: This does not answer the question